# App Server not responding to Web server, need timeout parameter

Tags: apache, http, server, config, passenger

When the web server gets an HTTP request, it serves the request by calling the app server. The app server is taking a long time to respond to the web server for a specific request.

> Is there a configuration in the web server(**Apache, Phusion Passenger**) to set limit to the time that app server should take to respond for that particular request?

If yes,

> If the web server terminates the connection to the app server, will the process/threads and other resources in the app server that were created to serve the request from the app server, get killed/recovered?

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of Passenger Enterprise, called [PassengerMaxRequestTime](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengermaxrequesttime). It allows you to limit the time that your webapp may spend processing a request.